# git blame of particular lines inside all files filtered with grep command

Tags: git, blame, vim-fugitive, git-blame, git-grep

I know how to run gblame inside a file.

I know how to grep a content inside all files in a directory.

I'd like to see gblame of particular lines around that one that contains a content. Example:

```
$ blame -R "content" ./
```

I see a list of files. I want to gblame all of theme, and understand who has touched those lines of code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it with Perl:

```
git grep -n 'content' | perl -F':' -anpe '$_=`git blame -L$F[1],+1 $F[0]`'
```

and if you want to create a custom command you can add something like this to your gitconfig in the alias section:

```
gb = "!f() { git grep -n $1 | perl -F':' -anpe '$_=`git blame -L$F[1],+1 $F[0]`'; }; f"
```

Comment: For me, the first command did not display the file name. How can the command be extended to display the filename?

Comment: @Arun You can use the -f / --show-name option for blame, which will show you file names, so the command would be:
`git blame -fL$F[1],+1 $F[0]`

Comment: I ended up using `git blame -lf $F[1],+1 $F[0] | | git name-rev --stdin --tags --always` in order to see the closest release tag.

Answer (score 0):

find files with needle, for each file blame, and for each blame output search needle

```
for file in `grep -lr needle *`; do  git blame $file |grep needle ; done
```

You can add context with -C

```
for file in `grep -lr needle *`; do  git blame $file |grep -C5 needle ; done
```

Comment: In this context, git grep would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this little script to accomplish git grep + blame:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "" ] ; then
    echo "usage: $0 <term>" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

for file in $(git grep $1 | cut -d ':' -f 1 | uniq) ; do
    echo $file ::
    git blame $file | grep $1
done
```

Comment: I modified this to be .bash_profile addable by kicking out the #!/bin/bash and just writing 
function ggb {
your content
}
. works like a charm. nice! Thanks for sharing this.